# AppLovin Ads in Unity3D : onAppLovinEventReceived not fired

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine, applovin

I used Applovin fullscreen ads in Unity3D iOS game.

Ads are working good. But event listener not fired. I wish to track fail event call.

```
public static void StartApplovin () 
    {
        AppLovin.SetSdkKey("My_SDK_Key");
        AppLovin.InitializeSdk();

        AppLovin.SetUnityAdListener("ApplovinListener");
    }
```

Here is ApplovinListener.cs class

```
public class ApplovinListener : MonoBehaviour {

    void onAppLovinEventReceived(string ev)
    {
        Debug.Log ("\n\nonAppLovinEventReceived\n\n");

        if(ev.Contains("DISPLAYEDINTER")) {
            // An ad was shown.  Pause the game.
        }
        else if(ev.Contains("HIDDENINTER")) {
            // Ad ad was closed.  Resume the game.
            // If you're using PreloadInterstitial/HasPreloadedInterstitial, make a preload call here.
            AppLovin.PreloadInterstitial();
        }
        else if(ev.Contains("LOADEDINTER")) {
            // An interstitial ad was successfully loaded.
        }
        else if(string.Equals(ev, "LOADINTERFAILED")) {
            // An interstitial ad failed to load.
            GameCenter2.ShowAdmobAds ();
            Debug.Log ("\n\n Applovin FAILED\n\n");

        }
    }

 }
```

When I run, Xcode gives below console log.

```
SendMessage: object ApplovinListener not found!
```

How to get onAppLovinEventReceived called ?

**UPDATE:** I have fixed this problem by creating gameObject

In Unity Manu, Press GameObject->Create Empty

Name it “ApplovinListener”

Now attach script named ApplovinListener to game object. That’s it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ApplovinListener` script must be attached to the name of the GameObject that is passed into the `AppLovin.SetUnityAdListener` function in order for the `onAppLovinEventReceived` function to be called.

You had this:

```
AppLovin.SetUnityAdListener("ApplovinListener");
```

Make sure that there is a GameObject actually named "ApplovinListener". Now, make sure that the `ApplovinListener` script is attached to it. The  `onAppLovinEventReceived` function should be called after you do this.

---

To make this easier for you, I recommend you do this instead:

```
AppLovin.SetUnityAdListener(yourGameObject.name);
```

then attach the `ApplovinListener` script to that GameObject you referenced above.

Comment: Thank you..I got email from Applovin and they also suggested same to create GameObject named ApplovinListner...Its working now.