# Are my Applovin callbacks working correctly in Unity 3d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, listener, integration, applovin

I'm not sure if I've set up my event callbacks correctly, where would these events be firing to? I've setup test ads and all the different types of ads are working correctly.

I've got a game object UI_Menu with my listener attached to it like so

```
AppLovin.SetUnityAdListener("UI_Menu");
```

But none of the events are firing

```
public void ShowInterstitial()
{
    Log("Showing interstitial ad");

    // Optional: You can call `AppLovin.PreloadInterstitial()` and listen to the "LOADED" event to preload the ad from the network before showing it
    // Showing utilizing PreloadInterstitial and HasPreloadedInterstitial
    if (AppLovin.HasPreloadedInterstitial())
    {
        // An ad is currently available, so show the interstitial.
        #if UNITY_ANDROID

                    AppLovin.ShowInterstitialForZoneId("998d2ed211ae3efc"); // For Zone Non-RewardedFullScreen3
        #endif
    }
    else
    {
        // No ad is available.  Perform failover logic...
    }

}



void onAppLovinEventReceived(string ev)
{
    Debug.Log("called");
    Log(ev);
    if (ev.Contains("VIDEOBEGAN "))
    {
        Debug.Log("working");
        // An ad was shown.  Pause the game.
    }
    else if (ev.Contains("HIDDENINTER"))
    {
        // Ad ad was closed.  Resume the game.
        // If you're using PreloadInterstitial/HasPreloadedInterstitial, make a preload call here.
        AppLovin.PreloadInterstitial();
    }
    else if (ev.Contains("LOADEDINTER"))
    {
        // An interstitial ad was successfully loaded.
    }
    else if (string.Equals(ev, "LOADINTERFAILED"))
    {
        // An interstitial ad failed to load.
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the second script attached to the object called `UI_Menu`? Did you try using `Applovin.SetUnityAdListener(gameObject.name);` instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AppLovin Ads in Unity3D : onAppLovinEventReceived not fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46484572/applovin-ads-in-unity3d-onapplovineventreceived-not-fired)

Comment: It's working now, but where do the calls go on the analytics side?